# findViewById return null, my_view.getID() not equal to R.id.my_view

Tags: android, view, unity-game-engine, r.java-file, findviewbyid

I write a Unity android plugin, have this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_portrait);
webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview_content_port);
```

activity_main_portrait.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".UJMPPActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_top" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_back_port"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_top"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_btn_back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_home_port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_left"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_activity_bottom_icon01" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_return_port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_left"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_activity_bottom_icon02" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_refresh_port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_left"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_activity_bottom_icon03" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_facebook_port"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ujmpp_bg_activity_left"
        android:src="@drawable/ujmpp_activity_bottom_icon04" />
</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_content_port"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this plugin can work well on an empty unity project

but webview get null on another unity project with other android pulugins (facebook, google IAB..etc)

I try to print the view hierarchy and R.id.*

**first project (empty):**

```
Display R.id / webview_content_port, 2131165200
.../.../ Child at 2 = android.webkit.WebView{419a8d58 VFEDHVCL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070010 app:id/webview_content_port}, id=2131165200
```

**second project:**

```
Display R.id / webview_content_port, 2131165200
.../.../ Child at 2 = android.webkit.WebView{419ab618 VFEDHVCL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f040013 app:id/webview_content_port}, id=2130968595
```

Why the view id changed? and how to fix it? or other way to get view like using findViewById?

** This issue will cause many packages null exception occurred

** When I put my custom layout from the res / layout is removed, the other packages will be back to normal

Comment: **"Why the view id changed?"** Resource ids are auto-generated and held in the R.java class. Just because you use the same name in the layout file doesn't mean that two different projects will generate the same id. That shouldn't be a problem and it's why we use `findViewById(...)`. Try cleaning your project - it could simply be the R.java file has become corrupted or out of sync.

Comment: I don't know is how to generate view-id using setContentView(R.layout.xxx). If a different  Unity project will produce a different ID, that really a big problem.

Comment: @Squonk project->clean not works.

Comment: I found the same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118209/multiple-plugins-unity-4-1-2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Unity will regenerate the resource ids when it builds your app, but your old resource ids are already compiled into your plugin.

The solution, which I found [here](http://www.twodee.org/blog/?p=4951), is to get your ids by name:

```
// instead of webview = this.findViewById(R.id.webview_content_port);
int webviewID = getResources().getIdentifier("webview_content_port", "id", getPackageName());
webview = (WebView)findViewById(webviewID);
```